# How to debug a program in VS Code as administrator

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I'm using Tracy to debug C++ code, but a lot of its features are restricted if the program isn't run as administrator. I'm debugging with VS Code and would like not to have to use a different debugger to do this. I've tried starting VS Code as an admin and debugging but it didn't change anything.

With VS Code's unfortunate naming, anytime I try to lookup how to do this I just get results for how to do it with Visual Studio.

Comment: Does VSCode have an 'attach to process' function?  If so, you should be able to launch the program 'as administrator' and then attach to it.

Comment: Isn't Tracy a php debugger?

Comment: @PaulSanders Yes it does, I think what I could do is write a batch script to compile and run the program as admin and then have code attach to it.

Comment: Use CLion instead.  Unlike VS and VScode it can debug in admin mode by using an elevator that only elevates the debuggee and so you don't need to run the IDE in admin mode...

Answer (score 0):

you can install the code runner extension on vs code
[you can see it in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zvZQ.png)